# storing variable values in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios5, objective-c-2.0

we do have a calculator app in ios5 and we want the users to set their own values to our calculators variable buttons such as "x" or "y". For example the user set "x=5" and wants to do the calculation of" x + 5 = " the result should be 10 anyway.how do we make the program store the temporary values of variable defined by user in an NSMutableDictionary

Comment: Check out NSExpression, it may work better than what you are proposing...

Answer (score 8):

Create the `NSMutableDictionary`, convert the number to an `NSNumber` and put it into the `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *customValues = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

float value = 5;

NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberForFloat:value];
[customValues setObject:number forKey:@"x"];
```

or using literals replace the above two lines with:

```
customValues[@"x"] = @(value);
```

Or are you asking a different question?